# How do you offset instances using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I'm trying to make cartoon style hair with geometry nodes, to be more specific, a pony tail, by instancing a bezier curve. The issue is the stands pass through each other at the top. How can I Vector each segment to pass over the stands rather than pass through them?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Just don't use instances. Use the new hair system (3.5) instead.